# "ambiguous symbol" in Bazel building C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build, bazel, cl

## Background

I am on Windows building with Bazel using cl to compile C++.

#### Subset of files:

```
third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/schriter.h
third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/utypes.h
third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/stringpiece.h
third_party/icu/source/common/stringpiece.cpp
third_party/icu/BUILD
a/a.cc
a/a.h
a/BUILD
b/cpp/src/strings/stringpiece.h
b/cpp/src/util/uri_utils.h
b/BUILD
```

`schriter.h` has `#include "unicode/utypes.h"`.

`uri_utils.h` and `b/cpp/src/strings/stringpiece.h` both have `class StringPiece`. `third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/stringpiece.h` has `class U_COMMON_API StringPiece : public UMemory`

`a.cc` refers to `StringPiece` and has these includes:

```
#include "b/cpp/util/uri_utils.h"
#include "strings/stringpiece.h"
#include "third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/schriter.h"
```

#### `a/BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "a",
    srcs = ["a.cc"],
    hdrs = ["a.h"],
    deps = [
        "//third_party/icu:common",
        "//b:sdk_strings",
    ],
)
```

#### `b/BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "sdk_strings",
    srcs = [
        "cpp/util/uri_utils.cc",
        "cpp/src/strings/stringpiece.cc"
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "cpp/util/uri_utils.h",
        "cpp/src/strings/stringpiece.h",
    ],
    includes = ["cpp/src"],
)
```

#### `third_party/icu/BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "common",
    srcs = [
        "source/common/stringpiece.cpp",
        "source/stubdata/stubdata.c",
    ],
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
)
```

## Problem

As is, building `third_party/icu:common` fails with: 
 `third_party/icu/source/stubdata/stubdata.c(20): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/utypes.h': No such file or directory`

If I add `copts = ["/Ithird_party/icu/source/common",],` to `third_party/icu/BUILD`, then `icu:common` builds but target `a` fails with:
`third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/schriter.h(21): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/utypes.h': No such file or directory`

If instead I add `includes = ["source/common",],`, then `icu:common` builds but target `a` fails with:

```
a/a.cc(168): error C2872: 'StringPiece': ambiguous symbol
b/cpp/util/uri_utils.h(24): note: could be 'StringPiece'
third_party\icu\source\common\unicode/stringpiece.h(52): note: or 'icu_54::StringPiece'
```

The source compiles fine using cmake, so I shouldn't need to change the source. How do I change the BUILD files to make this build correctly? How do I let everything in `icu` access the headers in `unicode`, but not expose `unicode/stringpiece.h` to targets that depend on `icu`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the namespace (`icu::StringPiece`, I'm guessing?) to resolve the C2872 error.

For limiting visibility, check out [the documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#hdrs):

> For cc_library rules, headers in hdrs comprise the public interface of the library and can be directly included both from the files in hdrs and srcs of the library itself as well as from files in hdrs and srcs of cc_* rules that list the library in their deps. Headers in srcs must only be directly included from the files in hdrs and srcs of the library itself.

This means that `hdrs` define transitively visible headers and `srcs` is for "private" headers.

However, as the docs points out further down, this cannot always be perfectly enforced:

> Unfortunately Bazel currently cannot distinguish between direct and transitive inclusions, so it cannot detect error cases where a file illegally includes a header directly that is only allowed to be included transitively. For example, Bazel would not complain if in the example above foo.cc directly includes baz.h. This would be illegal, because foo does not directly depend on baz.

So, it should prevent all but the most determined user to put it in the `srcs` of a private target with a `copts = ['-Ithird_party/icu/source/common']` option.

Comment: I moved all the .h files from `hdrs` to `srcs`, but get the same errors as before. Regarding icu::StringPiece, I don't want to use that in `a.cc`, I want to use the other StringPiece

Comment: icu_54? Then specify `icu_54::StringPiece`.

Comment: No, I want to use cpp/src/strings/stringpiece. I don't want the icu stringpiece.h to be visible to `a.cc`, but it needs to be visible to `schriter.h` when building `a.cc`. I did this using cmake with `target_include_directories(icucommon PRIVATE source/common)`, but can't seem to achieve the same result with Bazel.

Comment: This is now resolved. I think the root problem was that our project was using relative paths for its #include statements. I changed them all the absolute paths, and now it doesn't try to use icu_54::StringPiece when it should use a different StringPiece.